# How can I make DFA of the following condition?

Tags: dfa, deterministic, automaton

Please help me to make the DFA of the following condition:

> L = { w: n<sub>a</sub>(w) mod 3 > n<sub>b</sub>(w) mod 3 },

where n<sub>a</sub>(w) represents the number of occurrences of `a` in w and n<sub>b</sub>(w) represents the number of occurrences of `b` in w.

Comment: Let's get started. Every DFA has an initial state. What would you say are the transitions from the initial state to other states, and what are the conditions for those transitions? You can also have one or more states that accept the string `w` if it has no more symbols.

Answer (score 0):

First of all design DFA for n(a)mod3 horizontally and with its initial state design n(b)mod3 vertically .....It will take total 9 states and mark states (a,b) where a is n(a)mod3 and b represents n(b)mod3 and then make the states having first element of tuple greater than the second as final states(there will be 3 in this case).....hope my answer will help

Answer (score 0):

The only things we need to keep track of are the number of occurrences of a and b mod 3, respectively. There are three possibilities for each of a mod 3 and b mod 3 (0, 1 or 2, respectively) and since these are independent we can be in a total of nine states:

- q00: a mod 3 = 0, b mod 3 = 0
- q01: a mod 3 = 1, b mod 3 = 0
- q02: a mod 3 = 2, b mod 3 = 0
- q10: a mod 3 = 0, b mod 3 = 1
- q11: a mod 3 = 1, b mod 3 = 1
- q12: a mod 3 = 2, b mod 3 = 1
- q20: a mod 3 = 0, b mod 3 = 2
- q21: a mod 3 = 1, b mod 3 = 2
- q22: a mod 3 = 2, b mod 3 = 2

These will be the states of our DFA. The transitions are as follows:

- from state qij, transition to qij' on input a, where j' = (j + 1) mod 3
- from state qij, transition to qi'j on input b, where i' = (i + 1) mod 3

This gives us a total of 18 transitions.

We want to accept when a mod 3 > b mod 3; that is:

- state qij is accepting iff j > i

That gives us 3 accepting states.

Finally, our initial state occurs when we have seen zero instances of either symbol; that is:

- the initial state is q00

We have now fully defined the DFA for this language.